# How to remove an element where a particular class above id doesn't exist with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hi this is the code that is being generated automatically:

```
<div class="divider"></div>
<article class="link"></article>
<div class="divider"></div>
<article></article>
<div class="divider"></div>
<article></article>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Now I don't like to see the first divider so `$("divider").first().css("display", "none");` works fine.

However any article with the class "link" has to be hidden `$("link").first().css("display", "none");`

This leaves the second divider playing the role of the first divider, So I need to hide that also. I can't say hide the second divider are that is not always the case. It could even be

```
<div class="divider"></div>
<article class="link"></article>
<div class="divider"></div>
<article class="link"></article>
<div class="divider"></div>
<article class="link"></article>
```

In this case I would need to hide all the dividers.

I need something link if an article does not exist before the .divider then hide it

Any help? thanks

Comment: What is the actual result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd firstly hide all the `.link`s, with

```
$('article.link').hide()
```

and then hide all the `.divider`s that precede the `.article` (in this way you won't see two `.divider`s one after the other) with

```
.prev('.divider').hide();
```

Finally I'd hide the first `.divider` with

```
$('.whatever-container-you-have > .divider:first-child').hide();
```

Wrapped all together it becomes:

```
$('article.link').hide().prev('.divider').hide();
$('.whatever-container-you-have > .divider:first-child').hide();
```

that should fit what you need.

Comment: Thanks how can I say .next('.divider') as well as prev() as now that I tried it it seems that I need to remove the divider on top of the link (as you did) as well as the one bellow

Comment: no worries I got what I needed. Used: $('article.link').siblings('.devider').hide(); to get the divider bellow as well

Answer (score 0):

just get all the article that has the link class, hide them and hide the previous siblings also and you are done, something like:

```
  $('article.link').hide().prev('.divider').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
$('article.link').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text() === ""){//if the article is empty
         $this.hide();//hide it
         //Hide the previous element if it has the class divider
         $this.prev('.divider').hide();        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, i've tested it on js fiddle

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <article class="link"></article>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <article></article>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <article></article>
    <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('article.link').hide();
      deleteDividerDiv();

});

function deleteDividerDiv() {


    var firstDiv = $("div.container").children(":visible").first();

    if($(firstDiv).is("article")) {
        return;     
    } else if($(firstDiv).is("div") && $(firstDiv).hasClass('divider')) {
       $(firstDiv).hide();
       deleteDividerDiv();
    } 

}
```

Try this on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbwRm/42/)